# Add shortcut for iTerm on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard, iterm, shortcut-menu

I am trying to add shortcut for opening iTerm when I press F1. I added an application shortcut with this key but it does not work. I want to fire iTerm instantly irrespective of what application is currently running when I press F1. Any help would be appreciated.

I recently moved to mac from Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://iterm.sourceforge.net/scripting.shtml
as mentioned in this solution: https://superuser.com/questions/455915/mac-os-how-can-i-launch-the-iterm-terminal-with-a-specific-profile-from-autom

It is not just creating the shortcut, you need to tell iTerm to actually "open a new terminal". Otherwise, the best you can get is to have the last active terminal to pop-up and get into focus.